# unable to load certificate when convert cer to pem

Tags: ssl, https

I am using this openssl `OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017` command to convert cer to pem:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in fullchain.cer -out fullchain.pem
```

but shows error:

```
unable to load certificate
140025671485328:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1220:
140025671485328:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:386:Type=X509
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That error is consistent with an input file that is not in the binary DER format.

I *suspect* that when you actually look at `fullchain.cer` it will already be in the [PEM](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/PEM) format (base64 ASCII encoded) and looks a bit like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...abcd...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...abcd...
-----END CERTIFICATE----
```

Comment: what should I do with this certificate? just rename it to pem?@Rob what should I do to make this command work?

Comment: That or use it "as is". (In linux file extensions are more informational and usually don't the define/limit the function of a file.) None of the applications I know really care if I point them at `fullchain.cer` `fullchain.pem` or `fullchain_of_my_cert` or whatever other file name as long as that file has the right content